# TypeError: val.split is not a function

Tags: javascript, string, loops, split

Hi I'm getting this error. Is their anything wrong in the code?

```
var lineamt = 431.45;
var taxamt = 20;
var sum_val = lineamt+"-"+taxamt;
var line = '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkdata" id="checkdata' + i + '" onclick="sum_value('+sum_val+',this.checked)" style="position: inherit"/></td>';

        function sum_value(val, chk) {
          total = document.getElementById('line_amount').value\
          if (chk == true) {
            var res = val.split('-');
            linetotal = parseFloat(res[0]) + parseFloat(res[1]);
            total = parseFloat(total) + linetotal;
            alert(total);
          }
        }
```

The variables that I'm passing are inside loop. but nothing seems wrong if I remove val.split() function. but if I try to do with that it gives this error

Comment: Where is `val.split() ` in your code?

Comment: Also this line looks like have typo total = document.getElementById('line_amount').value\

Comment: Sorry, I was trying without val.split. now i have edited the code @AnkitAgarwal

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Currently you’ve shown us code that throws a different error, has no `dataJson` or `i` defined, and `sum_value` isn’t called, since `line` is never included into the DOM.

Comment: What value val contains?

Comment: val contains (lineamt-taxamt ) like (431.56-20) @IngusGraholskis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `val.toString().split('-');`

I think its because your val is not a string